# randomly losing dns resolving ability

Tags: linux, networking, dns, reply

I am seemingly randomly, but frequently (every few mins) losing my internet connectivity.
The problem is not on the ADSL modem, but on the Linux router, that follows. A DNS server (bind) is running on the Linux router and when I can't access webpages , I realised, it is because I get no replies to my dns requests.

using the command `tcpdump -ni eth1 -s 128 port 53`

I send dns queries but don't get a reply. For example:

```
02:41:48.188398 IP 192.168.231.165.2898 > 128.63.2.53.53: 6525 A? ns2.denic.de. (30)
02:41:48.188480 IP 192.168.231.165.34131 > 128.63.2.53.53: 62058 AAAA? ns2.denic.de. (30)
02:41:48.188531 IP 192.168.231.165.44951 > 128.63.2.53.53: 60509 A? ns3.denic.de. (30)
02:41:48.188715 IP 192.168.231.165.57460 > 128.63.2.53.53: 22077 AAAA? ns3.denic.de. (30)
02:41:48.188884 IP 192.168.231.165.64112 > 128.63.2.53.53: 43050 AAAA? ns1.denic.de. (30)
02:41:49.680811 IP 192.168.231.165.51734 > 62.169.194.48.53: 34223+ AAAA? PLUS.GOOGLE.COM. (33)
02:41:49.833793 IP 192.168.231.165.34709 > 198.41.0.4.53: 18062 A? ns1.denic.de. (30)
02:41:49.834410 IP 192.168.231.165.55421 > 198.41.0.4.53: 37252 A? ns2.denic.de. (30)
02:41:49.834465 IP 192.168.231.165.32204 > 198.41.0.4.53: 9728 A? ns3.denic.de. (30)
02:41:49.834589 IP 192.168.231.165.36391 > 198.41.0.4.53: 25022 AAAA? ns2.denic.de. (30)
02:41:49.834726 IP 192.168.231.165.61125 > 198.41.0.4.53: 65397 AAAA? ns3.denic.de. (30)
02:41:49.834810 IP 192.168.231.165.39314 > 198.41.0.4.53: 52550 AAAA? ns1.denic.de. (30)
02:41:50.362847 IP 192.168.231.165.41937 > 62.169.194.48.53: 9737+ [1au] AAAA? CSI.GSTATIC.COM. (44)
```

IP address `192.168.231.165` is my side.

This question is following from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/626925/no-internet-while-downloading-torrents-seems-dns-related?noredirect=1#comment780957_626925) question, but apparently the problem occurs even when I am not downloading torrents.

since with torrents I could sort of avert the problem by limiting the download & upload rate of my torrents, I checked with iptraf the incoming / outgoing rate of packets.

When my connection works smoothly, the inc/outg are up to 12/24 kbps.
when I can't access webpages (for the 2-4 mins duration) the rates are reduced abit compared to the above - but that could be an error on my part (due to limited observation sample).

I can't find a pattern as to why I don't get dns replies... my [named.conf](http://pastebin.com/AaSWhz9M) doesn't show anything in the logs. still there may be an error in my config as the `queries.log` is always empty. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Check you forwarders (in named.conf) in the order they are. Use `nslookup` for example for that.

Comment: how could I do that with nslookup? I am not sure exact what to check...

Answer (score 0):

You address (192.168.231.165) is simply not allowed to make a query to the server as it is not in the trusted ACL.

```
allow-query { trusted_subnets; };

acl trusted_subnets {
  local_nets;
  vpn_subnet;
  synthnassizer_subnet;
  dsa_office_subnet;
  skails_dns;
  synthnassizer_dns;
  dsa_dns;
  m2g_dns;
};

acl outbound_subnet {
  192.168.231.0/24;          // Your address is matched here
};
```

You can check [this doc](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/queries.html#allow-query) on `allow-query` option in config.

Comment: The ip address you see, is the `eth1` in my server and it is the internet-side iface (ie. it is connected to an adsl modem). To be honest I do not want the dns server to answer queries that originate on the internet side, just queries on the intranet side (and some vpn sites too). So I shouldn't add `outbound_subnet` in my `allow-query` statement. What do you think?

Comment: Wait a minute. 192.168.231.165 is your local address still. It's behind your ADSL modem/router's NAT. It is safe to let it make queries as it has nothing to do with the Internet. Internet is on the other side of the router. If I understand your setup correctly

Comment: internet is on the other side of the ADSL modem (not the router). The router is a linux pc. This side of the ADSL modem ( that connects to the router is just a DMZ). Thing is , there are no queries done from the ADSL<->Router subnet, or at least thats what i think. What you see above is just the BIND server quering ISP, GOOGLE and OpenDNS dns servers for domains it doesn't itself know about. or am I not thinking this right...? Also if what you propose in your reply is true, then I shouldn't have internet altogether, instead of losing it randomly. no?